# RavenDb - Query by number of times something is in a subset

Tags: ravendb

Considering the following pseudo data-model "Shop" which contains Brands:

```
Shop:
{
   Id ... etc ...
   Name: "General sports store",
   Brands: {"Adidas", "Nike", "Puma"}
}
```

Given a certain list of brands, I want to find the shops that sell similar things.

For example, given the following shops:

- Niketown: Nike
- Some other store: Nike, Adidas
- Wrong store: Hugo Boss

When I search for "Nike, Adidas", I want to find both "Niketown" and "some other store", since they have our brands.

"some other store" should be the first result since it sells the most of our brands we request. (can I use boosting for this?)

However, "wrong store" should not be found, since it doesn't have any of the brands we requested...

How should I approach this with RavenDb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input is a single string of `"Nike, Adidas"` then you first need to remove the comma because it's not part of the token "Nike" that will be in the database.

But then you can simply search normally.  The behavior you described is the default.  Boosting is not required, because multiple matches will already have a higher score and be raised to the top.

```
var searchTerms = "Nike, Adidas";
searchTerms = searchTerms.Replace(",", "");
var results = session.Query<Shop>().Search(x => x.Brands, searchTerms);
```

*However*, I noticed that you have some terms that are multiple words ("Hugo Boss").  This will throw off the search because it is expecting single word tokens.  In other words, this won't return any results:

```
var searchTerms = "Hugo Boss";
var results = session.Query<Shop>().Search(x => x.Brands, searchTerms);
```

You have some options for how to handle this.  If you want to continue to use the `Search` method, you would need to make sure the input string had quotes around the multi-word term.  You also need to tell raven not to escape these strings.  So this would work:

```
var searchTerms = "\"Hugo Boss\"";
var results = session.Query<Shop>().Search(x => x.Brands, searchTerms,
                                 escapeQueryOptions:EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery);
```

But it might be a bit tricky to get the input to line up properly in all cases.  So another technique you might want to consider is using the `In` operator.  This will work quite well if you are sure to have commas separating the search terms as you described.

```
var searchTerms = "Adidas, Nike, Hugo Boss";
var items = searchTerms.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim());
var results = session.Query<Shop>().Where(x => x.Brands.In(items));
```

Comment: Considering the "In" approach. Would that also surface the best result on top? (with the most matching brands)

Comment: Yes.  Unless you change the ordering, that is the default behavior.